# What is my problem while inputting the script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, node.js

MY NODEMON IS NOT RUNNING. IT IS SHOWING `nodemon : File C:\Users\Mahobano\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be  loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more  information, see about_Execution_Policies at  https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.`
`At line:1 char:1`
`+ nodemon index.js`
`+ ~~~~~~~`
`+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException`
`+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess`
IN RESULT WHEN I INPUT `nodemon index.js`.

Comment: I downvoted because you've demonstrated that you've successfully failed to **actually read the error message** and follow the basic instructions **included in the error message** which tell you exactly how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security policies running scripts on vs code is disabled by default, and there is a lengthy process to change the policy to enable particular command, however, there is a shorter way to do that. just follow the below instructions:

Go to: C:\Users\Mahobano\AppData\Roaming\npm
Find nodemon.ps1
and delete this file and now nodemon will work on vs code